# Change select input the angular way

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a `select` input with ng-change attribute. In my controller I use the hotkeys module and bind shortcut keys to a function that selects one of the options of the element. The reason I'm not setting the underlying model is that the element has `ng-change` that I wish to invoke. I tried setting `selectedIndex`, but that doesn't cause anything to change (not even the result of the underlying model) except the element. Tried to wrap in `$apply` and got an error. Tried to use `$timeout` with no delay parameter, and that didn't help either.

Comment: could you create a plunkr of the same?